# OOP inheritance of attributes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm facing some issues in OOP with inheritance inside a class with specific attribute. I have still not found an easy solution, but maybe I don't have the good keywords.

OK so let's say i have the following classes :

```
public class Video{  
}

public class Movie extends Video{
}

public class TVSerie extends Video{
}
```

Both Movie and TVSerie should have an attribute which is a list of actors. 
However actors could be slightly different for TVSerie and Movie, so i created the following Actors classes :

```
public class Actor{
    String name;
    String role;
}

public class MovieActor extends Actor{
    double compensation;  
}

public class TVSerieActor extends Actor{
    boolean guestStar;
    int numberOfEpisodes;
}
```

Basically all i want is to access a list of Actor in an instance of Video but I don't really know where to declare each list. 
Right now, I've added a list of specific Actor for TVSerie and Movie, but it doesn't seem right because i have to check the type of my Video instance to get a list of specific actor while all i need is the parent actor.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of problem can be addressed with generics, by using bounded type parameters:

```
public class Video<A extends Actor> {
    protected List<A> actors;

    public List<A> getActors() { return actors; }
}

public class Movie extends Video<MovieActor> {}

public class TVSerie extends Video<TVSerieActor> {}
```

This way you'll be able to use the list of concrete `MoveActor`s if you know the `Video` is a `Movie`, but you'll also be able to to use the same list as a mere `List<Actor>` list if you don't know (or care) what kind of `Video` an instance actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Using your existing classes, why not put..

```
protected List<Actor> actors;
```

in your Video class? This way, each Movie or TVSeries instance will have its own list of actors.  By using the protected keyword, you are allowing the two subclasses to access the variable.  Then just assign the appropriate actor subclass when you instantiate or modify the list.

```
public class Video{

     protected List<Actor> actors;

     public Video(){
          actors = new ArrayList<Actor>();
     }

     // Here you can get the actors for any instance of
     // Video or any of its subclasses
     public List<Actor> getActors(){
           return actors;
     }
}

public class Movie{

     public Movie(){

          super();

          //read movies from db etc..
          actors.add(new MovieActor());
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe even default package scope, if those classes are in the same package.

Comment: Generics are not covariant, so you can't have `List<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<MovieActor>();`

Comment: Thanks. Edited with the appropriate solution.